# Odoo: One2many field not working

Tags: python, xml, odoo, one-to-many

I've encountered strange behaviour of a one2many field in Odoo.

This is my code:

models.py:

```
class mrp_bom_inherit(models.Model): 
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'
    producten_tussenmodel = fields.One2many(comodel_name='tussenmodel_wc_producten', inverse_name='bom_id', string="producten", copy=True)

class tussenmodel_wc_producten(models.Model):
    bom_id = fields.Integer()
    routing_id = fields.Integer()
    producten = fields.Char(string="Productnr.")
```

views.xml:

```
<field name="producten_tussenmodel" widget="one2many_list" nolabel="1">
    <tree string="Een Naar Veel" editable="bottom">
        <field name="producten" domain="[('routing_id', '=', 32)]"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

This gives as output:

[image]

But it should only show "bbb" since "bbb" is the only record in the database with routing_id = 32 in table tussenmodel_wc_producten and bom_id in table tussenmodel_wc_producten equals an id in mrp.bom.

I've checked this via an SQL query:

```
select producten
from mrp_bom as m JOIN tussenmodel_wc_producten as t ON(m.id = t.bom_id) 
where t.routing_id = 32
```

Which has as only output "bbb".

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:** Some more screenshots for Ludwik Trammer:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`domain` attribute on a field only controls **which objects are present on a list of available objects** (i.e. objects that can *potentially* be chosen for the relation) when the user edits a form. It doesn't do anything more than that and specifically it doesn't control which objects are actually in the relation.

If the objects is **already** in a relation with "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" and "ddd", setting a domain won't do anything to change that.

Comment: I tried to understand this but it's quite hard to understand for me. So the domain I've put in my views, doesn't do anything right? But I guess there has to be some way to select the values to show? I have to put my domain somewhere else?

Comment: Could you make the same screenshot, but with a larger context around it, so I can make sure I interpret it correctly?

Comment: I've added them in my OP.

Comment: Ok, so you can only use the `domain` attribute on form fields, not tree fields. You can change which objects are in the relation by editing the form and adding/removing them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to update the relation in model, for One2many relation you must take Many2one field as inverse field name, So that odoo engine can interpret it properly.

```
class tussenmodel_wc_producten(models.Model):
    bom_id = fields.Many2one('mrp.bom','Bom')
```

And also update your field domain in that way,

```
<field name="producten_tussenmodel" widget="one2many_list" nolabel="1" domain="[('routing_id', '=', 32)]">
    <tree string="Een Naar Veel" editable="bottom">
        <field name="producten" />
    </tree>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem, on your one2many field, the inverse argument is suppose to point to a many2one on the other table, i.e. the inverse of the relationship, whereas in your code above, bom_id in tussenmodel_wc_producten is an Integer.

You should redefine as

fields.Many2one("mrp.bom", "BOM Id")

One final thing; tussenmodel_wc_producten doesn't define an _name for the model.  This is legal as the base model will default to class.**name** if _name isn't defined, but it is convention to either define _name or _inherit.  Given how important _name is in Odoo model processing, I wouldn't like to rely on everything working as expected if it isn't defined.